# How to sort list of object based on list of object in another list/master list in C#?

Tags: c#, sorting

I have following object structure -

```
public class Student
{
        public int RollNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Division { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have 2 list of object as follows: 
1) Master List -

```
var masterList = new List<Student>
{
                new Student {RollNumber = 1, Name = "Jim", Division = "A"},
                new Student {RollNumber = 10, Name = "Mike", Division = "A"},
                new Student {RollNumber = 8, Name = "Peter", Division = "A"},
                new Student {RollNumber = 4, Name = "Sandy", Division = "A"},
                new Student {RollNumber = 7, Name = "Michale", Division = "A"}
};
```

2) SubList

```
var subList = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student {RollNumber = 4, Name = "Sandy", Division = "A"},
                new Student {RollNumber = 7, Name = "Michale", Division = "A"},
                new Student {RollNumber = 1, Name = "Jim", Division = "A"},
                new Student {RollNumber = 10, Name = "Mike", Division = "A"}
            };
```

I want to sort my sublist w.r.t the object order in the masterlist like after applying sorting the order of object in SubList should be as -

```
new Student {RollNumber = 1, Name = "Jim", Division = "A"},
new Student {RollNumber = 10, Name = "Mike", Division = "A"},
new Student {RollNumber = 4, Name = "Sandy", Division = "A"},
new Student {RollNumber = 7, Name = "Michale", Division = "A"}
```

Is it possible to achieve such sorting logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming RollNumber is the identifying field:

```
var orderedSubList = subList.OrderBy (
    s => masterList.IndexOf(masterList.FirstOrDefault(m => m.RollNumber == s.RollNumber))
);
```

Comment: Thanks Kaarel for providing optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

//Assuming that there are no duplicate records.

```
        var masterList = new List<Student>
                            {
                                new Student {RollNumber = 1, Name = "Jim", Division = "A"},
                                new Student {RollNumber = 10, Name = "Mike", Division = "A"},
                                new Student {RollNumber = 8, Name = "Peter", Division = "A"},
                                new Student {RollNumber = 4, Name = "Sandy", Division = "A"},
                                new Student {RollNumber = 7, Name = "Michale", Division = "A"}
                            };

        var subList = new List<Student>
                            {
                                new Student {RollNumber = 4, Name = "Sandy", Division = "A"},
                                new Student {RollNumber = 7, Name = "Michale", Division = "A"},
                                new Student {RollNumber = 1, Name = "Jim", Division = "A"},
                                new Student {RollNumber = 10, Name = "Mike", Division = "A"}
                            };


        List<Student> sortedList = new List<Student>();

        foreach (var item in masterList.Select(x => x.RollNumber))
        {
            if (subList.Where(x => x.RollNumber == item).FirstOrDefault() != null)
                sortedList.Add(subList.Where(x => x.RollNumber == item).First());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible but you should ask yourself what identifies a Student. Because the lists currently do not contain the same students with respect to the object identities.

If it was, i.e. if `masterList` and `subList` really contained the same objects, you could simply order them by

```
subList.Sort((s1, s2) => masterList.IndexOf(s1).CompareTo(masterList.IndexOf(s2));
```

Otherwise you have to identify the students e.g. using the RollNumber.

*Edit:* In comparison to the answer by kaarel, this solutuion would sort the list in place, while the solution of kaarel might be easier to read.